# Normalising images using mean and std of a dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, std, mean

I used the following snippet to compute the `mean` and `std` of the images in the `cityscapes` dataset to normalise them:

```
def compute_mean_std(dataloader):
    
    pop_mean = []
    
    pop_std = []
    
    for i, (img,mask, rgb_mask) in enumerate(dataloader):
        
        numpy_image = img.cpu().numpy()
        
        batch_mean = np.mean(numpy_image,axis=(0,2,3))
        pop_mean.append(batch_mean)
        
        #print(batch_mean.shape)
        
        batch_std = np.mean(numpy_image, axis=(0,2,3))
        pop_std.append(batch_std)
        
        #print(batch_std.shape)
        
        
    pop_mean = np.array(pop_mean).mean(axis=0)
    pop_std = np.array(pop_std).std(axis=0)
    
    print(pop_mean.shape)
    print(pop_std.shape)
    
    return(pop_mean, pop_std)
```

This code gave me the following `mean` and `std`:

- `MEAN = [0.28660315, 0.32426634, 0.28302112]`
- `STD = [0.00310452, 0.00292714, 0.00296411]`

but when I computed the `mean` and `std` of images after normalisation using these `mean` and `std`, they are not close to `0` and `1`.

Is this approach correct to compute `mean` and `std` over the whole dataset and normalising images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulas are not correct. You can't take the mean of the values of a batch and then the standard deviation of these means and expect it to be the standard deviation over the entire dataset. Try something like:

```py
total = 0.0
totalsq = 0.0
count = 0

for data, *_ in dataloader:
    count += np.prod(data.shape)
    total += data.sum()
    totalsq += (data**2).sum()

mean = total/count
var = (totalsq/count) - (mean**2)
std = torch.sqrt(var)
```

Comment: @MasoumehJavanbakht the mean and std of the pixel values of a single image has no guarantee of being representative of the mean and std of the entire dataset. Imagine you have an all white image, it will have std 0.

Comment: @MasoumehJavanbakht if you wish to do it per channel, yes.